# Is it possible to decompile a .NET 5.0 WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am familiar with .NET Framework. And I use C# for my program that uses .net framework. But I want to change it to .net 5.0. As I googled it, there are many tools to decompile .net framework (i.e. `dnspy, d4dot, Justdecompile`, etc.) But when I write code using .net 5.0, it seems that the program I made can't be used in the decompiler.

I had tried to decompile my own .net 5.0 app using:

```
1. de4dot (Error saying "The file isn't a .net PE")
2. dnspy
3. Telerik JustDecompile(Error saying "supported only valid clr")
```

I am curious, can .net 5.0 be decompiled like .net framework or not?

Comment: Unpack? I don't know this term: do you mean decompile? Have you tried out ILSpy or JetBrain dotPeek or .NET Reflector?

Comment: Try using JetBrains' dotPeek. It works really well for me.

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes I mean decompile. sorry for using wrong word.

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. The answer is of course "Yes", but then you ultimately want to know "How?". And the answer to that is "write code to do it, or find a tool that does it for you". Writing a decompiler is too broad for Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow isn't here to find tool recommendations. You'll have to research and find your own decompiler.

Comment: Have you tried ilspy?

Comment: I use JetBrains' dotPeek for when I can't find production code of internally developed programs but have the executable. Since C# .NET is pretty much just code slapped into an interpreter, dotPeek doesn't a great job at stripping the interpreter and giving line-for-line code returned.

Comment: @Symon .NET is not [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) but [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) runtime [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation): it is an *intermediate* level between the interpretation as in firsts BASIC and the native machine code as obtained with C compilers and linkers. The role of the virtual IL .NET assembly language and the CLR/JIT being to be more efficient than the execution in real time while offering a software independence from the machine.

Comment: @OlivierRogier , I always just took the fact it was bytecode with a JIT compiler as it being _technically_ interpreted but not _literally_ as there's still actual compilation necessary for it to run. Though, I can see how that may be confusing and overall _untrue_.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, .NET applications can be decompiled. To do that use the `.dll` file, not the `.exe` file. The `.dll` file is a CLR assembly that contains the compiled application logic. The `.exe` on the other hand is a native assembly that is used to start the app, but it doesn't contain any application-specific logic. You can even start the application without the `.exe` file using the command `dotnet application.dll`.

It's also worth mentioning that to properly decompile .NET 5 applications the decompiler at hand has to have proper support for .NET 5. For JustDecompile at least that's not the case. Sadly, it seems that it has been abandoned and hasn't received any meaningful updates since 2017. [CodemerxDecompile](https://decompiler.codemerx.com) is the spiritual successor of JustDecompile, building on top of the same decompilation engine and adding support for the latest frameworks and features.

*Disclosure: I'm part of the team behind CodemerxDecompile.*